Apache 2.2 Sever was fetching the required data to show the results from a shared folder. After upgrade to Apache 2.4 is complaining of UNC path
Using Apache 2.2 Server, I have an html page which is fetching the results from the shared folder and display the same.
For vulnerability issues, Started using Apache 2.4.62.
The upgraded apache was complaining of UNC path. So modified from backward slash to forward slash.
E.g  Apache 2.2 --> \SharedServer\SharedPath\Folder to //SharedServer/SharedPath/Folder.
After the changes, the Apache 2.4 is running but when the required link is selected, It says 404 error.( its not able to read the data from the shared folder)

The http server cannot somehow read a folder. It can only be told to either create an automatic index to represent the contents of a folder, or it can be told which files to use as a folder index inside a requested folder. Maybe you simply forgot to configure that? Your current question is unclear in what you actually mean by "the results from the shared folder". What "results"? What is that?

It also is unclear where //SharedServer/SharedPath/ should point to. The leading double slash does not make any sense, a valid and absolute posix path starts with a single leading slash, such path will always be interpreted relative to the file system's root node. Or you want a relative path, then you don't want a leading slash at all.
